# Setting and Saving UITextView Scroll Position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextview, nsuserdefaults

I would appreciate any help on this. I've looked all around and see that I could use `contentOffset.y` for this issue but no concrete ways of HOW to use it.

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UITextView` that takes up the whole screen. The `UITextView` is populated by a .txt file that is quite long. (think book length) How can I find the last scroll position of the textView, save it, and open the view to that same spot when the user returns to that view? I'm guessing that `NSUserDefaults` would be needed to save the position?

I've seen uses for :

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

and

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

and putting code into:

```
viewWillDisappear OR viewDidDisappear
```

and

```
viewWillAppear
```

but none of it seems to do anything for my situation.

Help a noobie out, please!

**LATEST EDIT:**

This is the latest iteration.  In the comments I described the current situation where the textview will remain in the same spot as long as there is no other scrolling going on.  For example, I run the app, the scroll position is, say {0, 30281.5}.  Without scrolling anything, I navigate to a different part of the app and then go back to the scrollview.  It is in spot {0, 30281.5}, exactly where I left it.  I close the app, run it again, same thing {0, 30281.5}.  BUT if I scroll from there, then the new scroll position is noted when I leave the page and noted again when I come back to the page.  They are both recorded to be the same new position but the textview is no where near where I left it.  I hope I explained this right.  Thanks to anyone who looks at this!

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint positionY;

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

        [_readerTextView setContentOffset:self.positionY];
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        _positionY = CGPointFromString([defaults objectForKey:@"savePosition"]);

        _readerTextView.contentOffset = _positionY;
        NSLog(@"OFFSET LOCATION IS NOW: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(_positionY));

    }];
} 

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    _positionY = _readerTextView.contentOffset;
    self.readerTextView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
    [_readerTextView setContentOffset:self.positionY];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:NSStringFromCGPoint(_positionY) forKey:@"savePosition"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    NSLog(@"OFFSET LOCATION IS: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(_positionY));   
}
```

Comment: What you describe sounds about right. What's the actual problem? If your attempted solution failed, update your question with what you actually tried and explain what issue you are having.

Comment: Maybe you can try - (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews. I have a similar problem until used in it.

Comment: Can you log the offset value the moment it is saved and the moment its loaded? i am guessing it works, but i just doesn't go exactly where the user left the scrollView.

Comment: @Beto, could you describe how you implemented it?

Comment: @Erakk, I logged it as you suggested, and you're right, the CGPoints are the same! {0, 13608.5}  But, how do I get it to show up on the screen in the same area?  It returns to a completely different spot.  How is that possible?

Comment: As a test, do the loading logic on the `viewDidAppear` and wrap it in `[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        //set the scrollView origin here
    }];` so it will update the origin on the next update cycle.

Comment: @Erakk, I tried your suggestion with the block.  If I open the app, go to the page that scrolls, leave it like it is with no scrolling, navigate to a different section of the app and then navigate back to the scroll page, it is in the same position.  But then I try to scroll down the page, navigate away and come back again, the scroll does not return to the same place.  Crazy, isn't it?

Comment: If the issue is that the saved value doesn't return *Exactly* where it should have saved, then i jut found out i have the same issue, and i follow the same logic as yours, though i save my in Core Data... to resolve this i am thinking of creating scrolling checkpoints, like rounding down the saved value and maybe performing another logic when saving to see if the saving value is close tho the already saved.
Also, i think ill debug the frame of the textView to see why he gets the wrong position.

Comment: Doesn't seem like it should be this difficult.  Thanks for your suggestions @Erakk.  Hope you can figure out a work around. I'm going to keep trying as well.